# Is there a way to combine Docker images into 1 container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I have a few Dockerfiles right now.

One is for Cassandra 3.5, and it is `FROM cassandra:3.5`

I also have a Dockerfile for Kafka, but t is quite a bit more complex. It is `FROM java:openjdk-8-fre` and it runs a long command to install Kafka and Zookeeper.

Finally, I have an application written in Scala that uses SBT.

For that Dockerfile, it is `FROM broadinstitute/scala-baseimage`, which gets me Java 8, Scala 2.11.7, and STB 0.13.9, which are what I need.

Perhaps, I don't understand how Docker works, but my Scala program has Cassandra and Kafka as dependencies and for development purposes, I want others to be able to simply clone my repo with the `Dockerfile` and then be able to build it with Cassandra, Kafka, Scala, Java and SBT all baked in so that they can just compile the source. I'm having a lot of issues with this though.

How do I combine these Dockerfiles? How do I simply make an environment with those things baked in?

Comment: You don't combine docker images, you compose then: https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: @generalhenry if I wanted to, couldn't I just copy and paste docker stuff needed to get Cassandra 3.5 and put that into my main Dockerfile that gets me Java, Scala and SBT?

Comment: While you could get everything running in a single container, it's rarely desirable.  Containers allow you to cleanly separate your networking, scaling, logging, monitoring etc . . .

Comment: @generalhenry Sure, that is often what you want to do. But what if you need rust to compile a binary python package from PyPi? In this case you might want to combine rust and python docker images. Composing them won't work.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can, with the **multi-stage builds** feature introduced in Docker 1.17

Take a look at this:

```
FROM golang:1.7.3
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=0 /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

Then build the image normally:

```
docker build -t alexellis2/href-counter:latest
```

From : https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

> The end result is the same tiny production image as before, with a significant reduction in complexity. You don’t need to create any intermediate images and you don’t need to extract any artifacts to your local system at all.
>
> How does it work? The second FROM instruction starts a new build stage with the alpine:latest image as its base. The COPY --from=0 line copies just the built artifact from the previous stage into this new stage. The Go SDK and any intermediate artifacts are left behind, and not saved in the final image.

Comment: Suppose I want to combine two base images that have a lot going on and aren't maintained by me. E.g., if I want to run a Rust app that has GPU acceleration, I want my image to be a merge of `nvidia-docker` and  `rustlang/rust:nightly`. These images in turn are layed on top of other images. In order to do this using multilayer builds, I have to know and specify all of the files from one of the images that I want copied over to the other image - seems impossible, particularly as that set can change whenever the upstream image changes. Am I reading this right?

Comment: @masonk I have had success doing:
`FROM a/a:latest        FROM b/b:latest        COPY --from=0 / /`

Probably terrible practice, but it does work. It was mostly for my own curiosity than something I would use in production.

Comment: The damn thing does not work for me. It's like the first "FROM" gets completely ignored.

Comment: Same here: I want to do `FROM image1; CMD image1command; FROM image2; CMD image2command;` It's not working at all. Always just the 2nd command

Comment: that defeats the purpose of having containers doesn't it ?.

Comment: @LuizFelipe, no, why should it? This reduces code-replications.

Comment: @masonk For nvidia specific solution, you can use nvidia-container-runtime and --gpus flag to access GPU from docker. https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#gpu helped me.

Comment: @CGFoX Same here, only the second `FROM image` is loaded.

Answer (score 29):

You can't combine dockerfiles as conflicts may occur.  What you want to do is to create a new dockerfile or build a custom image.

TL;DR;
If your current development container contains all the tools you need and works, then save it as an image and upon it to a repo and create a dockerfile to pull from that image off that repo.

Details:
Building a custom image is by far easier than creating a dockerfile using a public image as you can store whatever hacks and mods into the image.  To do so, start a blank container with a basic Linux image (or broadinstitute/scala-baseimage), install whatever tools you need and configure them until everything works correctly, then save it (the container) as an image.  Create a new container off this image and test to see if you can build your code on top of it via docker-compose (or however you want to do/build it).  If it works, than you have a working base image that you can upload to a repo so others can pull it.

To build a dockerfile with a public image, you will need to put all hacks, mods and setup on the dockerfile itself.  That is, you will need to place every command line that you used into a text file and reduce whatever hacks, mods and setup into command lines.  At the end, your dockerfile will create an image automatically and you don't need to store this image into a repo and all you need to do is to give others the dockerfile and they can spin the image up at their own docker.

Note that once you have a working dockerfile, you can tweak it easily as it will create a new image every time you use the dockerfile.  With a custom image, you may run into issues where you need to rebuild the image due to conflicts.  For example, all of your tools work with openjdk until you install one that doesn't work.  The fix may involve uninstalling openjdk and use the oracle one, but all configuration you did for all the tools that you have installed broke.

Comment: This answer is out of date since the introduction of multi-stage builds.

Answer (score 28):

The following answer applies to docker 1.7 and above:

I would prefer to use `--from=NAME` and `from image as NAME`
Why?
You can use `--from=0` and above but this might get little hard to manage when you have many docker stages in dockerfile.

sample example:

```
FROM golang:1.7.3 as backend
WORKDIR /backend
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go .
RUN  #install some stuff, compile assets....
    
FROM golang:1.7.3 as assets
WORKDIR /assets
RUN ./getassets.sh

FROM nodejs:latest as frontend 
RUN npm install
WORKDIR /assets
COPY --from=assets /asets .
CMD ["./app"] 

FROM alpine:latest as mergedassets
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=frontend . /
COPY --from=backend ./backend .
CMD ["./app"]
```

Note: Managing dockerfile properly will help to build a docker image much faster. Internally docker usings docker layer caching to help with this process, incase the image have to be rebuilt.

Comment: This is GENIUS!!!!!!! LOVE IT!!!! I can now merge my base docker images with the images (of the same architecture/OS)

Comment: after wasting so many hours you saved me !!

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you *can* roll a whole lot of software into a single Docker image ([GitLab](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/~/dockerfile/) does this, with one image that includes Postgres and everything else), but [generalhenry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491845/generalhenry) is right - that's not the typical way to use Docker.

As you say, Cassandra and Kafka are **dependencies** for your Scala app, they're not part of the app, so they don't all belong in the same image.

Having to orchestrate many containers with Docker Compose adds an extra admin layer, but it gives you much more flexibility:

- your containers can have different lifespans, so when you have a new version of your app to deploy, you only need to run a new app container, you can leave the dependencies running;
- you can use the same app image in any environment, using different configurations for your dependencies - e.g. in dev you can run a basic Kafka container and in prod have it clustered on many nodes, your app container is the same;
- your dependencies can be used by other apps too - so multiple consumers can run in different containers and all work with the same Kafka and Cassandra containers;
- plus all the scalability, logging etc. already mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

### When might you want to "combine" Docker images?

As others are pointing out here, you typically don't want to put your database and you application into the same Docker image. Ideally you want a Docker image to wrap a "single process"/"runtime". This allows each process to be scaled up/down and restarted individually.

Let's say you want to use some shared C-libraries/executables that are not available in the package manager of the image you are using, but someone else has created [an image where they are precompiled](https://hub.docker.com/r/graphblas/graphblas) - and you might not want to recompile these binaries as part of your build (depending on how long this takes). Is there a way to quickly create a POC-Docker image containing all of these executables/libraries based on the existing images?

### Docker and Composition

Relevant discussion: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3378

What Docker lacks is a good way of composing images. You can copy individual files or entire file systems from other images into your own using `COPY --from=<image> <from-path> <to-path>`. There is no builtin way of copying the environment variables from another image into your own.

That said, I have personally created a [custom frontend/parser for Dockerfiles](https://github.com/bergkvist/includeimage) that adds an `INCLUDE <image>`-keyword. This copies the entire filesystem, along with the environment variables into your image:

```sh
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t myimage .
```

```
#syntax=bergkvist/includeimage
FROM alpine:3.12.0
INCLUDE rust:1.44-alpine3.12
INCLUDE python:3.8.3-alpine3.12
```

### nixpkgs.dockerTools

if you want truly composable Docker builds, I recommend checking out [dockerTools](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#sec-pkgs-dockerTools) in [nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs). This will also result in more [reproducible](https://r13y.com/) (and typically very small) images. See https://nix.dev/tutorials/building-and-running-docker-images

```sh
docker load < $(nix-build docker-image.nix)
```

```hs
# docker-image.nix
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  python = pkgs.python38;
  rustc = pkgs.rustc;
in pkgs.dockerTools.buildImage {
  name = "myimage";
  tag = "latest";
  contents = [ python rustc ];
}
```

Comment: May I ask how to use your project? Do I need to install GoLang? What to do after I install GoLang? Do I run the .go file after that? Or I just need to pull your project to my PC and that is it, the INCLUDE command is available?

Comment: @QuangHoàngMinh You only need to have Docker installed to use the syntax extension. `#syntax=bergkvist/includeimage` refers to the docker image that is used to interpret the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2):

Docker doesn't do merges of the images, but there isn't anything stopping you combining the dockerfiles if available, and rolling into them into a fat image which you'd need to build. There's times where this makes sense, however, as for running multiple processes in a container most Docker dogma will point to this as less desirable especially with microservice architecture (however rules are there to be broken right?)

Answer (score 1):

You could not combine docker images into 1 container. See the detail discussions in Moby issue, [How do I combine several images into one via Dockerfile](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3378).

For your case, it is better to not include the whole Cassandra and Kafka images. The application would only need the Cassandra Scala driver and Kafka Scala driver. The container should include the drivers only.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted an nginx server with some node.js ssr. I simply did:

```
FROM nginx:alpine-slim

RUN apk add nodejs-current npm
```

Then I added a shell script into `/docker-entrypoint.d/`, which starts a background process for my node.js server (via pm2).

Answer (score -3):

I needed docker:latest and python:latest images for Gitlab CI. Here is what I came up with:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y sudo
RUN sudo apt install -y docker.io
RUN sudo apt install -y python3-pip
RUN sudo apt install -y python3
RUN docker --version
RUN pip3 --version
RUN python3 --version
```

After I've build and pushed it to my Docker Hub repo:

```
docker build -t docker-hub-repo/image-name:latest path/to/Dockerfile
docker push docker-hub-repo/image-name:latest
```

Don't forget to `docker login` before push

Hope it helps

Comment: This answer could have been condensed as "install everything you need in the Dockerfile". Meanwhile, you could have installed docker starting with `FROM python`