# Docker merge containers

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

I have running multiple containers separately which connected to each other using defined network in docker-compose.yml and my application is running perfect, so I want to create only one image for those multiple containers for deploying to my private repository (image with tags), I want to know what is the best practice to do that.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

networks:
  lemp:

services:
  nginx:
    build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    target: webserver
  container_name: webserver
  volumes:
    - ./src/app:/var/www/html/app
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  networks:
    - lemp

php:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    target: app
  container_name: app
  volumes:
    - ./src/app:/var/www/html/app
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
  networks:
    - lemp
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.21.6-alpine AS webserver
COPY ./src/ ./var/www/html
COPY ./nginx/conf.d/app.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf
EXPOSE 80 443

FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine AS app
EXPOSE 9000
```

Comment: Are you asking for how to ship a compose file for your project, or how to combine multiple container images into a single image? Those are two very different questions.

Comment: I asked for how to combine multiple container images into a single image and then deploy this single image to repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39626579/596285

Comment: Unfortunately, that is far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unclear what you really need. You can publish the individual containers to your registry and provide a downloadable Compose file for anyone to use those containers *together*, which will pull each image, separately.

Otherwise, you would need to copy all relevant steps from one Dockerfile to the other. Note: If you are running unique entrypoint/commands (processes) in each Dockerfile, then this is considered bad practice.

**UPDATE**

Looking at your example, you could install php-fpm into the Nginx container, copy the PHP files, and just serve the static content from there. However, I would recommend keeping separate containers, for sure. Nginx should be replaceable as a reverse proxy.

Also, you don't have a correct multi-stage Dockerfile (using FROM twice doesn't merge anything), and your Compose file is just running the same image (context) twice on two different ports.

Comment: You mean that the best practice to provide a downloadable Compose and Docker file from the registry and that can be applies to the production without facing any issues, so when can I build an independent image using docker build command in the best way for this application.

Comment: The Dockerfile does not need to be distributed. You would build that, then push it to a registry. Then anyone can use your Compose file (or Kubernetes chart, if you want to support that) to pull your images from the Registry

Comment: From your update you mean to add more layers on the Nginx-alpine base image for installing php-fpm on this base one and to run it as a single image including my application but you don't recommend it, I wish I could reach you.

Comment: While you can install PHP into Nginx container, that's not recommended because Nginx doesn't depend on php and you should be 1) hosting your static assets (images, Javascript, static HTML, etc) separately, and 2) scaling your backend application (php container), separately, following best practices. This way, nginx could be replaced with Apache httpd container, or any other web server

Answer (score 2):

You should plan to distribute your `docker-compose.yml` file, or perhaps a simplified version of it, as the standard way to run your combined application.  If it requires two images, you'll need to push the two images separately to your repository; don't try to combine them.  Do make sure the images are self-contained so you don't need the source code separately from the images to run them.

The `docker-compose.yml` file should roughly look like:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx:
    image: registry.example.com/nginx:${TAG:-latest}
    ports:
      - '80:80'
  php:
    image: registry.example.com/php:${TAG:-latest}
```

Calling out a couple of things here: I've removed the unnecessary `networks:` declarations (Compose provides a `default` network that works fine) and the unnecessary `container_name:` declarations.  I've put in an `image:` line for each image in place of the `build:` block, and use an environment variable to inject the image tag.  For the `php` container I've removed the `ports:` declaration since you probably don't want that externally accessible.  Finally, for both containers I've removed the `volumes:` that override the image contents.

Next to this, put a `docker-compose.override.yml` file.  This is not something you'd distribute.  It can say:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.php
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
```

If you have both files, [Compose merges their settings](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).  So for a developer this adds in the `ports:` to directly access the PHP-FPM service if required, and `build:` blocks to explain how to build both images.  Since the combined Compose configuration has both `build:` and `image:`, `docker-compose build` will build images with the specified names tagged with your local registry name.

You should have a separate Dockerfile for each image you're building.  The Nginx image resembles what you already have; for the PHP-FPM container you need to make sure you `COPY` the code into the image.

```sh
# Dockerfile.nginx
FROM nginx:1.21.6-alpine
COPY ./src/ /var/www/html/
COPY ./nginx/conf.d/app.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf
```

```sh
# Dockerfile.php
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
COPY ./src/app/ /var/www/html/app/
```

Now you can build and run the application locally.  Double-check that it works correctly, *without `volumes:` overwriting the image code*.

```sh
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
curl http://localhost/
```

If this works, then you're set to distribute this.  Pick a tag (a date stamp or the current source control ID are good choices), build the images, and push them to a Docker registry.

```sh
export TAG=20220418
docker-compose build
docker-compose push
```

Now you can copy only the `docker-compose.yml` file, but none of the other files we've touched, to the remote system, or put it in a GitHub repository, or something else.  On that system, set `$TAG` to match, and run `docker-compose up` as usual.  Docker will automatically pull the images from the repository.  Since the images are self-contained, the *only* thing you need is the `docker-compose.yml` file.

```sh
scp docker-compose.yml there:
ssh root@there
```

```sh
export TAG=20220418
docker-compose up -d
```