# Gitlab CI - Combine two docker images into a single stage

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have this gitlab-ci.yaml file. Using this file I execute my k6.io load test from pipeline. Now I need to execute some FFmpeg commands during the run stage, and my question is how do I make the FFmpeg tool available to the run stage. Do I need to grab the image that has FFmpeg and add it next to grafa/k6 or something else?

```yaml
default:
  tags:
    - default

workflow:
  name: "$PIPELINE_NAME"

stages:
  - lint
  - setup
  - run
  - teardown

lint:js:
  stage: lint
  image:
    name: tmknom/prettier
    entrypoint:
      - ""
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
      when: always
  script:
    - prettier --check '**/*.js'

setup:
  stage: setup
  image: alpine
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
      when: always
  script:
    - echo 'set up!'

run:
  stage: run
  environment:
    name: run
  image:
    name: grafana/k6:latest
    entrypoint: [ "" ]
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - summaries/
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
      when: always  # Prevent pipeline run for push event
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
      when: always
  script:
    - ./run.sh

teardown:
  stage: teardown
  image: alpine
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
      when: always
  script:
    - echo 'tear down!'
```

I tried adding two name tags under the run stage for using two images but it didn't work and returned a syntax error.

```yaml
run:
  stage: run
  environment:
    name: run
  image:
    name: grafana/k6:latest
    name: linuxserver/ffmpeg
```

Comment: Hi @seal.r00t, you probably should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626579/is-there-a-way-to-combine-docker-images-into-1-container)